# Json multidimensional array does not showing anything in ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm trying to show errors in ajax response but it doesn't work when error count is more than 1. For single error code is working fine and properly showing appending error message into targeted `div`.

### Php Code

```
$response = array();
$totalFiles = count($nf_image['name']);
for($f=0; $f<$totalFiles; $f++) {
    $fsize = $nf_image['size'][$f];
    $checkSize = $this->checkFileSize($fsize);
    if($checkSize==1){
        $response['fileErr'][] = 'Your selected file ['.$nf_image['name'][$f].'] size is not allowed.';
        $error = 1;
    }

}
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

### JS Code

```
success:function(response){
    $(".newsfeedAlertFiles").remove();
    for(f=0; f<response.fileErr.length; f++) {
        //alert(response.fileErr[f]);
        $(".newsfeedResponse").prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger newsfeedAlertFiles"> <strong>Alert! </strong> '+response.fileErr[f]+'</div>');
    }   
}
```

When php return more than 1 response there is nothing showing in the console, also getting this `responseText ""` in the console.

Can anyone guide me where is the issue that i can fix it. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me regarding this. Thank You

Comment: What is `var_dump($response)` ?

Comment: @Rayon I added  `var_dump($response)` in the end of the function but it nothing showing in the console

Comment: What does it show in `response` tab ?

Comment: @Rayon `response` tab only showing when php return single record, when php return more than one than console does not `response tab` also.

Comment: It means issue is with `php` script... Open `php` page in browser and try...

Comment: @Rayon ohh okay.. I'm trying on php page

Comment: @Rayon yes you are right there is something wrong in php script

Comment: Just try `echo json_encode($response);`